# Problema con una conexion NodeJS y MongoDB con Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy intentando crear una conexion entre mongodb y nodejs, mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const pug = require('pug');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Conexion a MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/project');
//Creacion de la Base de Datos en un JSON
var usuarios = {
    email: String, 
    password: String
};

//Model 
var user_schema = new Schema(usuarios)
var User = mongoose.model('User', user_schema);


//vistas y configuracion
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static('public'));

//peticiones HTTP
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.render('index');
    console.log('Hiciste una peticion GET')
});

app.post('/', (req,res) => {

var datos = new User({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
});

datos.save(function (err, datos) {

            res.render('bienvenida')
});


//Puerto en el que se va a escuchar el servidor
app.listen(80, 'localhost', () => {
    console.log('Servidor iniciado correctamente');
});
```

Por supuesto lo estoy intentando con express y mongoose, entonces el error que me sale es este:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
>       at app.post (C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\server.js:34:22)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at serveStatic (C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:75:16)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at expressInit (C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\gacar\Desktop\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

y este es mi archivo pug para la vista:

```
extends ./layouts.pug
block contenido
    body
        div(class="container")
            form(action='/', method="POST", class="form-signin")
                .container
                    form.form-signin
                    h2.form-signin-heading Please sign in
                    label.sr-only(for='inputEmail') Email address
                    input#inputEmail.form-control(type='email', placeholder='Email address', name="email" required, autofocus='')
                    label.sr-only(for='inputPassword') Password
                    input#inputPassword.form-control(type='password', placeholder='Password', required, name="password")
                    .checkbox
                    label
                    input(type='checkbox', value='remember-me')
                    |  Remember me
                    button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block(type='submit') Sign in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu error basicamente es porque no estas jugando con el bodyparser, necesitas algo asi:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Te recomiendo que vayas usando sintaxis de es6 y ayudate con eslint.

[Express/Connect top-level generic - example](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#expressconnect-top-level-generic)